# Connect to proxy through VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, proxy

I would like to route all traffic in Windows 10 through a proxy, i.e. global proxy settings

I have this idea similar to 'Drony' on Android, that the computer connects to a VPN, and all traffic in this VPN is routed to the proxy.

However I cannot find any resources about doing this on windows.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot